# Are overriden css properties cancelled or just overriden?

Tags: css, properties, overriding

I mean,

If i do:

```
#item { background:url('image.jpg');}
```

and then in another stylesheet i do

```
#item {background:red;}
```

will the browser load image.jpg and then cancell it and set red, or will go straight to red? (without loading the image)

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will do both, since those two statements are the same as

```
#item { background: red url('image.jpg'); }
```

or

```
#item { background-color: red; }
#item { background-image: url('image.jpg'); }
```

In both cases, the background will have an image, and the entire area of the item element in red. So an opaque image, like a .png with transparency, would for instance be filled with red in the transparent areas as well.

However, as the script parses the CSS in a cascading fashion,

```
#item { background: url('image.jpg'); }
#item { background: url('anotherimage.jpg'); }
```

it will load "anotherimage" and ignore the other one.
The request isn't sent until the CSS is done compiling and determined the order of [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). In other words, the first image is overridden, and is therefore never requested.

The 'background' is actually a short hand property, like 'border', combining all of the different properties into a single statement.
Here is a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) about the 'background' property, scroll down and you can read about it.

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case, the browser should load the image and apply red at the same time, because those two definitions don't really overlap. It's like setting the attributes "background-color" and "background-image" individually. It makes sense as there could be a little background-image and a red background for the rest of the larger element.

In general, definitions are overridden, though, depending on what is called the specificity. Check this page for more on that http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/