# inline hack css lower to IE9 ? (or all non CSS3 capable browsers)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I need a hack to tarjet internet explorer lower to 9, or to be more specific; i need a **inline** CSS hack to tarjet non CSS3 capable browsers

```
_prop:val -> ie6
*prop:val -> ie6 & ie7
????????? -> ie8 & ie7 & ie8
```

I am using gradients and images for those browsers, but ie8 does not support it... so i want to **load** the alternate image only if necessary

(**please avoid** answers suggesting to use external stylesheet using conditional coments or using javascript. I know that this code would be invalid, but its just for one little thing. Plus i am curious to know if its posible :)  )

Comment: this is not working then: background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(221,221,221) 20%, rgb(255,255,255) 68%);

Comment: i don't now if it works with rgb(...,...,...) but 255,255,255 is white so you could get the hex values of your colors and simply insert it in my answer script !

Comment: I realize you only need this for a one-off situation, but there are most robust solutions that will meet your needs in every situation. See how [HTML5 boilerplate solves this problem](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) without conditional stylesheets or CSS hacks. Relying on CSS parser hacks is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this:

```
prop: val\9
```

Putting \9 directly at the end of any value will target just IE8 and below

Comment: This also targets IE9 in a lot of cases.
http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/ for some background information.

Comment: I've not seen it target IE9 by itself, although with a different selector, can't remember exactly what but it involves nth-child, it does match IE9 and *not* IE8...

Answer (score 4):

I am using gradients in IE8 in a project. It does work !

```
 <style>
        #gradient {
            color: #fff;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 10px;
            /* For WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome etc) */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00f), to(#fff));
            /* For Mozilla/Gecko (Firefox etc) */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00f, #fff);
            /* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FF0000FF, endColorstr=#FFFFFFFF);
            /* For Internet Explorer 8 */
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FF0000FF, endColorstr=#FFFFFFFF)";
        }
    </style>
```

for box shadow there seems to be a workaround like this:

```
.shadow {  
    zoom: 1;  
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=0, Strength=3)  
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=45, Strength=2)  
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=90, Strength=3)  
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=135, Strength=2)
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=180, Strength=3)
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=225, Strength=2)
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=260, Strength=3)  
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#999999', Direction=305, Strength=2);  
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222; /*Mozilla-basierte Browser (z.B. Firefox)*/ 
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222; /*WebKit-basierte Browser (z.B. Safari/Chrome)*/ 
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222; /*CSS3 Standard*/ 
 }
```

for border-radius there is no support until ie9, as far as I know. I'm using several jQuery plugins to achieve border-radius in IE. hope this code helped you !

Comment: is there soething similar to border-radius and box-shadow?

Comment: I have updated my question, look that up. box-shadow yes, but complicated and border radius no until ie9. But I'm using a plugin to achieve the effect of border radius via jQuery !

Comment: hey! thanks a lot but that seems to be text-shadow in ie http://jsfiddle.net/YcPDA/

Comment: i thougth you where posting box-shadow ^^

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a hack, since **no** current browser supports all of CSS3.

Instead, simply specify fallback properties for older browsers, like this:

```
#selector {
    background: url("gradient.png");
    background: gradient(...);
}
```

Comment: yes but that way image would be load and i wanted to prevent that. i rather -in my current situation- produce invalid code than slower code

Comment: Huh? The CSS property is evaluated before anything is loaded. You can [check yourself](http://phihag.de/2012/so/gradient-dl.html): The gradient file should not be loaded in a modern browser.

Comment: it might not be used but the image would be loaded in all browsers

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Have you tried that test page? The image never gets requested as long as the browser supports gradients.

Comment: well i will try in monday but according to this question i made http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428183/are-overriden-css-properties-cancelled-or-just-overriden i thought the request was going to be done anyway

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet In that question, you ask about whether `background-color` overwrites `background-image`, and since those are two different properties, the answer is no. It might get clearer if you unroll the compound `background` properties and use `background-xyz` instead.